# looking up the control value and run time in a sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query in MS Access that in `where` clause I have:

```
WHERE (((tb_KonzeptFunktionen.Konzept)=[Formulare]![frm_Fahrzeug]![ID]));
```

It takes long time to run, but when I delete this `where` clause the query runs less than a second.

Can I say that pass the `[Formulare]![frm_Fahrzeug]![ID]` as a parameter does not efficient? Or looking up the control value is slowing it down? If yes how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The db engine should retrieve the control's value almost instantaneously.  If that `WHERE` condition slows down your query significantly, it is more likely due to extra work the db engine must perform to retrieve the matching rows.  You can check this assumption by temporarily substituting a static known value in place of the control's value.

```
WHERE tb_KonzeptFunktionen.Konzept=1;
```

If the version with the static value is equally slow, create an index on `tb_KonzeptFunktionen.Konzept` and try again.

Comment: thank you for your answer ,Konzept has an Index and when I write this `WHERE tb_KonzeptFunktionen.Konzept=1;` instead of `WHERE (((tb_KonzeptFunktionen.Konzept)=[Formulare]![frm_Fahrzeug]![ID])); ` it is faster

Comment: Sorry for my bad english,I meant if I put 1 it is faster than before